nanopb protobuf callback - getting data out of the callback
This is the common way described on www to print the information contained in a string object withing a protobuf object.
bool print_string(pb_istream_t *stream, const pb_field_t *field, void **arg)
{
    uint8_t buffer[1024] = {0};

    if (stream->bytes_left > sizeof(buffer) - 1)
        return false;

    if (!pb_read(stream, buffer, stream->bytes_left))
        return false;

    printf((char*)*arg, buffer);
    return true;
}

My question is how to i get this string back into the scope of the call, im not interrested in printing my data to screen, i want to have it back to where the call was.
The setup of the callback is as seen below, for printing..
funcs.decode = &print_string;
arg = "%s\n";

is it possible to bring in a pointer to a char array through the arg, and do a malloc in the callback containing the information? (Sorry im not at my computer, so cant try - but im interrested in what others have done in this situation - using global variables is not what im aiming at..)
/Kim
Havent tried it, but hopefully i can get confirmation that this is the right way once i get to my computer.

Despite that you have removed your previous question and this is on a different topic, I would still suggest you to reconsider max_size. You can specify that in a separate .options file to avoid modifying the .proto file.

If I set a max size,i would limit the size. The .proto files is not something i have created. Its a set defining a standard,so I can not just inventar a limit. I deleted the other post as i found an anser.
